# GLTF VALIDATION ABORTED: Too many messages produced

Tags: 3d, blender, gltf

I'm currently learning GLTF and Blender basics.
I'm exporting my file proper way, checked out also on [GLTF Validator](https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Validator/) if my file is valid, and it says `yes`.
Checked out on [Babylon](https://playground.babylonjs.com/#9GFSPZ#1) and it's working fine.

But in VSCode it gives me an error, which is saying that: `VALIDATION ABORTED: Too many messages produced`

I cannot compile with that error, so I would be glad if I could get any help.

Here's raw link to file: [Click](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/szymonwilczek/Ramen-Shop/main/static/models/ramenShop/glTF/ramenShop.gltf)

Here's error with "working" preview on VSCode Extension for GLTF:
[image]

Error is in line one saying what I previously declared.

Comment: This might be something that needs to be reported to the glTF VSCode extension, you can find its issue tracker here: https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-vscode/issues

Comment: I guess not, since extension is working (that’s that right preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a setting for glTF validation max issues.  The default value is a bit low (200) for performance reasons, but on a good machine can be much higher.

[image: settings screenshot with max issues 1000]

This is stored in `settings.json` as `"glTF.Validation.maxIssues"`.

Hitting the max issues limit is considered (by the glTF Validator) to be an "error" regardless of whether the issues produced were errors, warnings, or just hints.  It likely means the glTF file has a large number of issues that could be addressed.  The "Problems" window in VSCode should show a list of these.

In the case of this Ramen Shop, I see a lot of "Vector3 at XXX... is not of unit length" kind of messages.  This may indicate degenerate triangles, or normal / tangent vectors that need to be recomputed.

The validator is also complaining that the tangents and texture coordinates are all unused, since there are no textures included with the model.  These are not "errors" though, and are safe to ignore.

Comment: Thanks. That will do the work.